# Transformar array de javascript a una array de Kotlin

Tags: javascript, array, kotlin

De una petición a una API obtengo una array de jsons con unos valores como string y me gustaría saber como poder parsearla como una array en Kotlin. La array que obtengo de la petición es algo así:

```
[{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Test1",
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "port": 10302,
    "id_slave": 1
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Test2",
    "ip": "192.168.1.2",
    "port": 502,
    "id_slave": 1
}]
```

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para realizar la petición

```
URL(apiUrl).readText()
```

Comment: Como referencia puedes ver otras respuestas a la misma pregunta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928803/how-to-parse-json-in-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Existe una libreria llamado [klaxon](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon) que te puede ayudar.

Aqui un ejemplo segun su documentacion:

```
val result = Klaxon()
    .parse<Person>("""
    {
      "name": "John Smith",
    }
    """)
```

En tu caso seria:

```
public Data(val id : Int, val name : String, val ip : String, val port : Int, val id_slave : Int);

val jsonString = obtenerJson();
val result = Klaxon().parse<Array<Data>>( jsonString );
```

Recuerda importar la libreria:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:5.0.1'
}
```